# Yii2 framework loaded js file return errors

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I using yii2 AppAsset component registered js file:

```
<?php

namespace backend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class DiyAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl  = '@web';
    public $css = [
        //'css/diy.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/base.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

}
```

the js file content:
[the js file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiLyR.png)

the js file loaded success,but chrome broswer show me the error:

[image: show erros]

[image: expland erros]

can everyboy help me?

Comment: Are you sure this js content and `base.js` are the same files?

Comment: @Bizley yes  sure .but some people told me the problme is 'CRLF's,cause 'Unix' and 'Windows' Carriage-Return Line-Feed are difference.i using sublime text2 editor and i setting 'view->line endings' to 'unix',but the errors still displayed

Comment: Well, not sure about that but there is no `alert(1);` line in the content of your js and it is visible on the screenshot so I'm not sure where the problem is actually.

Comment: try to change the file name. and test it again with other browser

Comment: Could you be so kind and show us whole `base.js` file contents?

Comment: @Bizley yes bro.Before that .the js file content is "alert(1);" and now is 'var a = [1,2,3]; console.log(a);'.i try clear assets dir cache

Comment: @smoqadam okey ,i try it

Comment: @Bizley .okey i re-upload js file contents

Comment: So the same error in chrome?

Comment: @Bizley i using firefox broswer.but the errors exist

Comment: @Bizley,@smoqadam bro,i changed the js file name ,i get the right result ,What are the reasons?

Comment: @Aiden : I don't know. It's just happend in Yii2 :D

Comment: @smoqadam ok,thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you use VirtualBox to run Yii2 application.

If yes - disable `sendfile` in your Apache or Nginx config. Check out this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/351#issuecomment-1339640)

Comment: yes bro ,my PHP running on Vagrant of Nginx .when I disabled  Nginx config `sendfile`. that work fine,thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

From the above discussion i can guess that there might be a problem with your yii2 generated asset files, ive tried duplicating your error but without success,

I had also got such an error before when i copy pasted a previous app to start developing another app from that, The way i solved it was to delete the generated assets files as yii2 will recreate the files when you run the application again

If you are using the advanced template

The assets to delete are located at the root directory that is the directory structure looks like

```
_protected
assets //delete the contents in here but dont delete the folder assets
backend
themes
uploads
 ....etc
```

I hope this helps